# How to take in users name, and display it along with a message, depending on the time of day (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the users name, along with a message depending on what time of the day it is. I've created a function to do this, which I've called using a submit button. However, when I click submit on the webpage nothing happens?, I have put 'Name' after each message so it displays the name the users has entered into the form. What've I done wrong in the code, I'm pretty confused right now. Thanks for any help offered, I've put the code below:

```
<div id="main"><h2>Type your name in here:</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
function runfunction()
{
var Datenow = new Date();   
 (Datenow.getHours() < 12 )  {     document.write("Good Morning!"); } else  
if ( Datenow.getHours() >= 12 && Datenow.getHours() <= 17 ) {  document.write("Good Afternoon,'Name'!"); } else   
if ( Datenow.getHours() > 17 && Datenow.getHours() <= 24 ) {     document.write("Good Evening,'Name'!"); } else  
if ( Datenow.getHours() > 24) { document.write("It's pretty late, 'Name', you should probably go to bed!");

}
</script>

<form action="">
<input type="text" name="Name" size="7" value="Name" />

<input type="button" name="process" onclick="runfunction()" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with your code:

1. You need to put your `script` tags after the elements are loaded.
2. Do not use `document.write()`.
3. The function `runfunction()` did not have a ending curly bracket `}`
4. You had a missing `if` keyword for the first `if` statement.

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h2>Type your name in here:</h2>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" name="Name" size="7" value="Name" />

      <input type="button" name="process" value="Submit" />
      <div id="message"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelector("input[type=button]").onclick = function () {
        var name = document.querySelector("input[type=text]").value;
        var m = document.getElementById("message");
        var Datenow = new Date().getHours();
        if (Datenow < 12) {
          m.innerHTML = "<br />Good Morning! " + name + "!";
        } else
        if (Datenow >= 12 && Datenow <= 17) {
          m.innerHTML = "<br />Good Afternoon, " + name + "!";
        } else
        if (Datenow > 17 && Datenow <= 24) {
          m.innerHTML = "<br />Good Evening, " + name + "!";
        } else
        if (Datenow > 24) {
          m.innerHTML = "<br />It's pretty late, " + name + ", you should probably go to bed!";

        }
      }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a `<input type="button" />` within a `<form>` it submits the `<form>`; without a specified `action` attribute the form is submitted to the current URL, which causes the page to reload.

To prevent this, you can use `event.preventDefault()` (which prevents the default action) or `return false` within the function you're calling:

```js
function runfunction(e) {
  (e || Window.event).preventDefault();
  var Datenow = new Date(),
    currentHour = Datenow.getHours(),
      name = document.querySelector('input[name=Name]').value;

  if (currentHour < 12) {
    document.write("Good Morning!");
  } else
  if (currentHour >= 12 && currentHour <= 17) {
    document.write("Good Afternoon, " + name + "!");
  } else
  if (currentHour > 17 && currentHour <= 24) {
    document.write("Good Evening, " + name + "!");
  } else
  if (currentHour > 24) {
    document.write("It's pretty late, " + name + " you should probably go to bed!");

  }
}
```

```html
<form action="">
<input type="text" name="Name" size="7" value="Name" />

<input type="button" name="process" onclick="runfunction(event)" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Also, it's probably best to cache a variable, the current hour, rather than repeatedly call the same method repeatedly to get the same value every time the script moves to a subsequent `else if` assessment.

Incidentally, the hour will, and *can*, never be greater than, or equal to, `24`; it'll move from `23:59:59` straight to `00:00:00`.

Comment: Should I just put } else if { document.write("It's pretty late, " + name " you should probably go to bed!");    as that would mean when  the clock passed over 23:59:59 it will just print it's pretty late anyway?

Comment: You *could* use `else { document.write('<your message here>'); }` but using `else if {...}` (without an assessment, `else if (assessment here) {...}`) is a syntax error, and will cause your script to fail.

Answer (score 0):

you have some minor errors like forgot to close the function.
and you can just return false on click to prevent form submit

```js
function runfunction()
{
  var Datenow = new Date();

  if(Datenow.getHours() < 12 )  {    
    
   document.write("Good Morning!"); 
  } 
  else if ( Datenow.getHours() >= 12 && Datenow.getHours() <= 17 ) 
  { 
    document.write("Good Afternoon,'Name'!"); 
  } 
  else if ( Datenow.getHours() > 17 && Datenow.getHours() <= 24 )         {             document.write("Good Evening,'Name'!"); 
  }
  else  if ( Datenow.getHours() > 24) { 
    document.write("It's pretty late, 'Name', you should probably go to bed!");

}}
```

```html
<div id="main"><h2>Type your name in here:</h2>



<form action="">
<input type="text" name="Name" size="7" value="Name" />

<input type="button" name="process" onclick="runfunction(); return false;" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, huge help! Especially since return false; takes the form away once the user has entered their name :)